# Differenece between TV Indoor antenna and Satellite Dish

Tags: antenna, tv

Satellite Dish for TVs enables you to gain access to paid tv shows through subscription.

I'd like to know if the Indoor antenna specs below can also get paid signals on the air and if it could be an alternative to Satellite Dish. Please do not consider the signal external interference's like the environment.

Antenna Specifications:

- Built-in High gain booster
- Gain Control Yes
- Retractable dipoles   are adjustable for best VHF reception
- Large UHF     loop improves image quality
- Power-on  indicator
- Input Voltage    AC 220~240V
- Working Voltage  DC 12V/100mA
- Reception Frequency  VHF: 47~230MHz
- UHF: 470~860MHz
- Blown-Up gain
- VHF: 15dB
- UHF: 20dB

Answer (score 3):

No.  TV satellites generally transmit around 10 GHz or so.  This allows the relatively small dish type antennas to be effective at picking up the signal.  The signals are so weak that they don't penetrate through walls and roofs very easily, so the antenna has to have a clear sky view.  The antenna has a built in low noise amplifier, block downconverter, and line driver to transfer the satellite signal to the cable.  The signals are encrypted so you need a satellite TV box to decrypt the signals as well as provide power for the amplifiers and downconverters in the dish.  Generally this box must also communicate with the satellite operator to get the latest encryption keys.

You won't be able to pick up anything other than regular broadcast television with that antenna.